# MySQL get Parent as Heading and children as items

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Hello I have a database structure like this and some data in it

```
id | parent_id | name

1 | 0 | Nissan
2 | 1 | 240SX
3 | 1 | 350z
4 | 0 | Toyota
5 | 4 | Camry
6 | 4 | Prado
7 | 1 | Skyline
8 | 4 | Hilux
```

I want to take Nissan as heading and after show all the models. As well Toyota as heading and it's models below it. How do I achieve this using one query? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should normalize your database or at least separate your columns so there is a manufacturer column and a model column. This will then help you do a query such as

```
SELECT * FROM CARS WHERE manufacturer = 'Toyota';
or
SELECT * FROM CARS GROUP BY manufacturer;
```

But the best practise would be to have a table for storing manufacturers and a table for storing all models of the cars, then a table for storing your cars itself which will have 2 columns that are referenced from the other 2 tables.

So this will become:
id | parent_id | manufacturer_id | model_id

1 | 0 | 1 | 2 |

2 | 1 | 4 | 1 |

3 | 1 | 3 | 6 |

4 | 0 | 3 | 9 |

you will then do a query to join the 3 tables

```
SELECT cars.id, cars.parent_id, cars.manufacturer_id, cars.model_id, t1.manufacturer_name, t2.model_name from CARS
JOIN manufacturer_table t1 
ON t1.manufacturer_id = cars.manufacturer_id
JOIN model_table t2
ON t2.model_id = cars.model_id
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should solve your problem:

```
SELECT
  child.*
FROM
  {your_table} parent
LEFT JOIN
  {your_table} child ON child.parent_id = parent.id 
                     OR (child.parent_id = 0 AND child.id = parent.id)
WHERE
  parent.parent_id = 0
ORDER BY
  parent.id, child.parent_id, child.name
```

`{your_table}` should be replaced in two places with your table's name (which you presented in the question).